# jquery submit doesn't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

The dialogue box parts of this script work but the form doesn't submit

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#audit_delete_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    if ($form.find('select[name="audit_id_select"]').val() == "") {
        $.msgbox("Please select an audit", {
        type:"alert",
        buttons: [
        {type: "submit", value: "OK"}
        ]
      });
    }else{
        $.msgbox("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this audit?", {   
        type: "confirm",
         buttons : [
            {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
            {type: "submit", value: "No"},
            {type: "cancel", value: "Cancel"}
          ]
      }, function(result){
          if(result == 'Yes'){
              $(this).submit()
          }
      });

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think the first one is working fine because you call e.preventDefault() which cancels the form submission. What jQuery msgbox plugin are you using? It sounds like it's not blocking the submit event...

Comment: I'm using this one http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-msgbox/92626

Comment: I'll be honest and say that I'm fairly certain it's my logic that's not right, this is a tried and tested plug in thats been around for ages, unlike my jquery skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `e.preventDefault();` anyway. Then issue the submit if the user confirms.

```
$(THE_SUBMIT_BUTTON_ID).click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if(...){...}
else{
        $.msgbox("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this audit?", {   
        type: "confirm",
         buttons : [
            {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
            {type: "submit", value: "No"},
            {type: "cancel", value: "Cancel"}
          ]
      }, function(result){
          if(result == 'Yes'){
              $("form#audit_delete_form").submit() // We only submit when prompted
          }
```

Comment: Yeah, this was going to be my initial suggestion too. Although it's strange that the plugin wouldn't block...but yeah, I say try it too.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't submit the form, i'll post my edited code

Comment: @tatty27 are you binding to the button? You have to bind to the form. I edited my answer.

Comment: @raam86 I'm not quite sure what you mean? I'm fairly new to Jquery

Comment: You have to select the form element. and ride from there.

Comment: ahh, I think I understand you, does it make a difference that my code is using submit whereas your answer is click?

Comment: ok, I used the click instead and all it keeps doing is asking me to select an audit and won't let me select one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36496/discussion-between-raam86-and-tatty27)